# Check whether a process is running or not Linux

Tags: linux, process

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
ps cax | grep testing > /dev/null

while [ 1 ]
do
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Process is running."
    sleep 10
else
    nohup ./testing.sh &
    sleep 10
fi

done
```

I run it as `nohup ./script.sh &`

and it said `nohup: failed to run command './script.sh': No such file or directory`

What is wrong?

Comment: I run it as nohup ./script.sh &

Comment: it said nohup: failed to run command `./script.sh': No such file or directory

Comment: So i would like to wonder is my code wrong or not

Comment: Hate to state the obvious but is your script actually *called* `script.sh`? And does it exist in the current directory?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `ps cax | grep testing > /dev/null`  This seems to be searching for a process containing the word `testing` in the filename, but then the result is discarded.

Comment: Yes, my script is called script.sh

Comment: Actually I am doing something like continuously check whether a process is stopped or not.

Comment: if(a process is running)
    then sleep 10 seconds
else
    run that process again
    sleep 10 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each newly created scripts on Linux, you should first change the permission as you can see the permission details by using

```
ls -lah
```

The following content may help you:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ];
do
date=`date`
pid=`ps -ef | grep "your process"  | grep -v grep | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'`
if [[ -n $pid ]]; then
    echo "$date - processID $pid is running."
else
    echo "$date - the process is not running"
    # script to restart your process
   say: start the process
fi

sleep 5m
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The file script.sh simply does not exist in the directory that you are issuing the command from.
If it did exist and was not executable you would get:
`nohup: failed to run command ‘./script.sh’: Permission denied

Answer (score -1):

Make sure  your script is saved as script.sh
and your executing nohup ./script.sh & from the same directory in which script.sh. 
Also you can give executable permission for script.sh  by

```
chmod 776 script.sh
```

**or**

```
nohup ./script.sh &
```

**Run as**

```
nohup sh ./script.sh &
```

Comment: actually I have done the above commands before but it seems giving me same result

Comment: I suggest using symbolic files access modes, rathen than archaic and error-prone numerics. E.g. `chmod +x script.sh` is both more readable and less error prone.